# Beginner questions about Python For Loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm currently trying to work through the Python pre-bootcamp session for Flatiron. I have advanced to For Loops section and read through the Read.me. For loops seem simple enough but it seems the curriculum has diverged away from the read.me during the lab.

I created two lists based on a dictionary. List number one was an index that i created from the dictionary `city_indices=list(range(0,len(cities)))`. List number two was just a basic list created out of the names of the cities in the dictionary but was just basic list `city_names=['string']` that outlined the names of the cities.

My confusion is that the lesson taught me how to run a for loop over two elements within the same list or dictionary but did not teach me how to For Loop two separate lists into one.

im probably missing something.

The assignment is to use both elements in a For loop to create a ranked list. 
`city_indices` and `city_names`.

Im having trouble identifying the `for` and the `in` part of the loop.

Comment: Could you share the code you have tried? We can help suggest how to improve your code, but we can't write the the code for you.

Comment: I am not sure what you want to do? Iterate over two loops and compare the elements with the same index? or iterate over a merge? or something totally different?

Comment: i havent written any code yet. I understand that you can't write code for me. I really need to identify is the purpose of the ```For``` and the ```in ``` portion. if you could provide some context here then I could write it myself.

Comment: @JQadrad what I would write if the code was pulled from the dictionary that Id created would be as follows: ```interation count= 1``` ```For City in cities:```

Comment: @JQadrad sorry... what I would write if the code was pulled from the dictionary that Id created would be as follows: ```rank_count= 1```....```For City in cities:```....```rank_count+=1```... ```Print( rank_count + '.', City[name])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In am not sure if I understood you correctly, but from my point of view you want to do something like this:

```
city_indices=list(range(0,len(cities)))
for i in city_indices:
    print("{}: {}".format(i, city_names[i]))
```

assuming `city_names` and `city_indices` have the same length.

Comment: actually,I came across the ```.format``` syntax during google searches and that seems easiest and but I have to use just a ```for``` loop and the newly created lists . Im having trouble identifying what ```for``` and ```in``` are in the context of two lists.

Comment: but yes! I cant use that format because they are looking for me to use only the things that have been defined in previous lessons and the platform has not covered ```.format``` thanks for the comment !

Comment: `print(str(i) + ":" + city_names[i])`  does the same as `print("{}: {}".format(i, city_names[i]))` but it was just to show you what is the iterator and which is the list.